# Express: Access path param inside router.use()

Tags: javascript, express

Consider the following setup.

```js
var router = require('express').Router();

function someMiddleware(id) {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    // do something with id
    next();
  }
}

router.use('/:pathId', someMiddleware(pathId) /*, add more middleware */); // doesn't work
```

How can I access the `pathId` in `router.use`? Is it even possible or do I need a different setup?

The reason why I don't want to access it via `req.params.pathId` inside of `someMiddleware` is that I want the middleware to be agnostic of the actual parameter name, so I can use it in different setups.

#### Edit

I came up with a solution via a wrapper middleware. It would look something like this.

```js
router.use('/:pathId',
  (req, res, next) => someMiddleware(req.params.pathId)(req, res, next));
```

This way `someMiddleware` can be unaware of the actual details of `req.params`.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add the middleware like this

```
router.use('/:pathId', someMiddleware, /* add more middleware */);
```

and inside your middleware, you can access the pathId like this

```
function someMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  const pathId = req.params.pathId;
  // do something with pathId
  // calling the next middleware as you mentioned
  next();
}
```

This should work as expected.

---

If you want your someMiddleware to be aware then try like this

```
router.use('/:pathId', (req, res, next) => {
  const pathId = req.params.pathId;
  someMiddleware(pathId)(req, res, next);
}, /* add more middleware */);
```

your function should be

```
function someMiddleware (pathId) {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    // do something with pathId
    next();
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to avoid this, since I need `someMiddleware` to be unaware of the implementation of req.params.

Comment: I see, in that case you need to move your someMiddleware call into a headless middleware